# Problematica con DataTable al cargar resultado de funcion con c#

Tags: c#, jquery, mvc, datatables

Tengo problemas al querer implementar el DataTable, estoy elaborando un buscador avanzado para lo cual, el buscador principal, lo cargo en showmdal con lo campos y botones necesario, el código de script esta en la view de index que tiene el siguiente código (aclaro que es una adaptación de un código que encontré), todo lo anterior esta en c#.

```
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">

    var assetListVM
    $(function () {


        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#result_table')) {
            $('#result_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('#result_table').dataTable().empty();
        }

        assetListVM = {
            dt: null,
            init: function () {

                dt = $('#result_table').DataTable({
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": _urlBase + "MtoInvesMercados/Get",
                        "data": function (data) {
                            data.search = $("#search").val();
                            data.FechaInicial = $("#FechaInicial").val();
                            data.FechaFinal = $("#FechaFinal").val();
                            data.CampoBusqueda = $("#CampoBusqueda").val();
                        }                            
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "title": "Número IM", "data": "NumeroInvestigacion" },
                        { "title": "Oficio CCA", "data": "OficioCAASolIm" },
                        {
                            "title": "fecha", "data": "FechaCCA", "type": "date",
                            "render": function (value) {
                                if (value === null) return "";
                                var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;//date format from server side
                                var results = pattern.exec(value);
                                var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));

                                return dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
                            }, "autoWidth": true
                        },
                        { "title": "Descripción", "data": "Descripcion" }
                    ],
                    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
                });
            },

            refresh: function () {
                dt.ajax.reload();
            }
        }

        // Advanced Search Modal Search button click handler
        $('#btn-PerformAdvancedSearch').on("click", function () {
            assetListVM.refresh
        });
        

        // initialize the datatables
        assetListVM.init();          



    });
</script>
}
```

el código en el controlador es el siguiente.

```
  public ActionResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel, AdvancedSearchImVM searchViewModel)
    {

        IQueryable<MtoInvesMercado> query = db.MtoInvesMercado;
        var totalCount = query.Count();

        query = SearchAssets(requestModel, searchViewModel, query);
        var filteredCount = query.Count();

        // Paging
        query.OrderByDescending(c => c.FechaCCA);
        query = query.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);



        var data = query.Select(im => new
        {
            //FechaRegistro = im.FechaRegistro,
            //Ejercicio=im.Ejercicio,
            OficioCAASolIm = im.OficioCAASolIm,
            FechaCCA = im.FechaCCA,
            //OficioDBTSolIm = im.OficioCAASolIm,
            //FechaDBT = im.FechaDBT,
            //OficioImEnvia = im.OficioImEnvia,
            //FechaIM = im.FechaIM,
            Descripcion = im.Descripcion,
            NumeroInvestigacion = im.NumeroInvestigacion
            //OficioDBTEnvia = im.OficioDBTEnvia,
            //FechaDBTEnvia = im.FechaDBTEnvia,
            //Comentarios = im.Comentarios,
            //ComentariosCCA = im.ComentariosCCA,
            //ComentariosDBT = im.ComentariosDBT,
            //OficioDBTSolicitaPMR = im.OficioDBTSolicitaPMR,
            //FechaDBTSolPMR = im.FechaDBTSolPMR,
            //ComentariosPMR = im.ComentariosPMR               
        }).ToList();

        return Json(new DataTablesResponse(requestModel.Draw, data, filteredCount, totalCount), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

ahora bien el error que me manda es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esperando contar son su apoyo.

gracias

Comment: Obviamente c# aca se te escapo no?

Comment: si es correcto perdon

Comment: Horacio, en tu perfil te han dado 47 respuestas a preguntas que has hecho y tu no has aceptado ni una, estas creando un mal precedente  hay que agradecer el esfuerzo del que ayuda

Comment: Así va a ser muy difícil ayudarte

Comment: Sabias que podes usar el boton [edit] y justamente arreglar eso?